# Controllers Communication Angular 1 Service vs events

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controllers

I have seen a similar question, but it does not satisfy my curiosity.

Let's suppose we have the webapp of Wallapop, and we have 2 panels:
   1: Filters
   2: Content

How should we communicate between these controllers, managing searching, filtering, pagination, etc.

1: The easy one to me would be events, with $rootscope.$broadcast and $scope.$on

2: Create a service which is Instantiated in the controller of the content and we are able to update it from the filters panel and also from the content view (a bit messy as far I have tried, you need to ensure that you reset the service ...)

3: User route-ui.. the question for this is... would it be just enough?

Thanks you for your time

Comment: show what you have created so far and we will help you

Comment: Keep in mind AngularJS is an MV* framework. The Model is the [Single Source of Truth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_source_of_truth). The framework creates the View from the Model. Events change the Model. The Model is the [Single Source of Truth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_source_of_truth).